# KivyMD: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using KivyMD now.

When invoking python code, the following error occurred.

I do not know why such an error occurred.

Please tell me how to fix it.

[Here is image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlxhl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `theme_cls` instance in your app class like this:

**(.py) file**

```
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

app = MyApp()
app.run()
```

**(.kv)** file

```
NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        #drawer_logo: "/user.jpg"
    Button:
        text: "i'm happy, what about you !"
```

[image]
[image]

Check this: [Kivymd Gitlab | Script 1](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py#L919)

All **kivymd** widgets are inherited from **ThemableBehavior** class - [Kivymd Gitlab | Script 2](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/theming.py#L340)